# Off-center X-Axis in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, image-resizing

I'm having an issue getting my boxplot to align with my x axis labels. I've tried adjusting the size of the chart, but the data points still look a little off. I appreciate any help!

This is the current chart:

[image: Current Chart]

Comment: Closed as a duplicate because the `dodge=False` answer in the duplicate is the older answer (2019-11-28). The accepted answer here, doesn't explain how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you're using two categorical variables; `x`, and `hue`. This creates a so called ["nested"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) (search for the key-word "smoke") box-plot, and if one of the categories is empty in some sense, might cause the observed off-set.

Answer (score 2):

This misalignment can happen when the `hue` argument is set.

You can add the `dodge=False` argument to the `sns.boxplot` function to keep boxplots aligned with the x-axis labels.

In your example, it would look like this:

```
sns.boxplot(x=df["Groups"], y=df["Rate per Month"], hue=df["Hours per Month"], dodge=False)
```

Description of the `dodge` parameter from the the [seaborn.boxplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#:%7E:text=dodgebool%2C%20optional,the%20categorical%20axis.) documentation:

> **dodge: *bool, optional***
>
> When hue nesting is used, elements should be shifted along the categorical axis.

[Example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#:%7E:text=Use%20hue%20without%20changing%20box%20position%20or%20width%3A) from the seaborn.boxplot documentation.